F-Test for multiple regression
In the Introduction to Statistical Learning using Python (ISLP) text, on page 85, the authors state that:
Sometimes we want to test that a particular subset $q$ of the coefficients are zero. This corresponds to the null hypothesis
$$H_0 : \beta_{p-q+1} = \beta_{p-q+2} = \ldots = \beta_p$$
where for convenience we have put the variables chosen for omission at the end of the list. In this case, we fit a second model that uses all the variables except those last $q$. Suppose that the residual sum of squares for that model is $RSS_O$. Then, the appropriate $F$-statistic is:
$$F = \frac{(RSS_O - RSS)/q}{RSS/(n-p-1)}$$
My Question.
When the null hypothesis is
$$H_0 : \beta_{m}=\ldots=\beta_n = 0$$
and the alternative hypotheses is
$$H_a = \exists \beta_j \neq 0, m \leq j \leq n$$
does it not imply that the multiple regression model we attempt to fit, uses the $(n-m+1)$ variables $X_m,\ldots,X_n$? That is:
$$Y = \beta_m X_m + \ldots + \beta_n X_n + \epsilon$$
I don't follow the author's assertion : we fit a second model that uses all the variables except those last $q$.

Could you please reformulate the title as your specific question?
